# Find the probability that at least one of the two events occurs

Tags: probability

If the probability that Joe will buy a pizza is $0.5$ and the probability that Elaine will buy a pizza is $0.35$, then what is the probability that at least one of the two will buy a pizza on their next visit to the pizza place?

I know that this is a very basic problem. However, I am a little confused about the "at least" statement in the question. I would really like to understand why the correct answer is correct, so please go in depth for how you got your answer. I am thinking that you might use the addition rule for probability, but again, the "at least" confuses me.

Comment: This seems to assume the **Axiom of handwaviness**:  Any two events that I care about are independent.

Answer (score 4):

It means you should consider the possibilities that $(a)$ only Joe buys a pizza, $(b)$ only Elaine buys a pizza, and $(c)$ both Joe and Elaine buy a pizza.

The only way the condition is not satisfied is if neither of them buys a pizza.  *If* the two people buy pizzas independently of each other, this happens with probability

$$
(1-0.5)(1-0.35) = (0.5)(0.65) = 0.325
$$

so the probability that at least one of them buys a pizza is $1-0.325 = 0.675$.

Comment: Isn't it equally valid and more simple to think of the question as an "or" probability where the two events are not mutually exclusive? i.e. P(either Joe or Elaine buys a pizza) = .5 + .35 - (.5)(.35) = .675? Also, could you explain how these are not mutually exclusive?

Comment: Oh, sure, that way is equally valid.  Whether it's simpler, of course, is in the mind's eye.  As far as "these" not being mutually exclusive goes, what do you mean by "these"?  Do you mean Joe and Elaine buying a pizza?  From your analysis, it seems clear that you understand they aren't mutually exclusive...